# how to access relationship and pass into a view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

a beginner question here, how can i get the building_name column on my buildings table which has a relationship with information, i wanted to access it inside the show function and display in on the show.views? And i also wanted to know how can i call it inside the show view Please help.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Information;
use App\Building;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;

class InformationController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    $buildings = new Building();
    $buildings::all();
    return view('create', compact('buildings'));
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'building_information' => 'required',
        'building_id' => 'required'
    ));

    //store in the db
    $information = new Information;

    $information->building_information = $request->building_information;
    $information->building_id = $request->building_id;

    $information->save();

    Session::flash('success', 'The information was successfully saved!');

    //redirect to other page
    return redirect()->route('information.show', $information->id);
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Information  $information
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $information = Information::find($id);
    return view('show')->with('information', $infomation);
}



<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Building extends Model 
{
public function information()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Information');
}
}


<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Information extends Model
{
 public function building()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Building');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add relationship and pass it to the view

```
public function show($id)
{
    $information = Information::with('building')->findOrFail($id);
    return view('show')->with('information', $infomation);
}
```

In your view:

```
{{$information->building->building_name}}
```

Comment: can u explain what with() and fixfindorfail() does()?

Comment: can you explain why you unaccepted my answer after the other guy edited and commented based on my answer!

Comment: oh, u can only accept 1 right answer sorry about that mate.

Comment: anyway can u pls answer my last question :)

Comment: with() loads the relationship with the spcific model in your case loads buildings relationship and takes it in the collection. findOrFail in case it fails finding the specific record it will throw an error

Answer (score 1):

Load the relationship too when getting the Information object:

```
$information = Information::with('building')->find($id);
```

If there are multiple buildings associated, you can loop through them in your blade view:

```
@foreach( $information->building as $building)
   <li>{{ $building->building_name }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: then how can i display them in views?